# nearest php based search using latitude and longitude from a large dataset

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

we have large database for search using latitude,longitude and radius. It takes long time for search whole database. we want to search not whole database only search specific area of range. we want to insert area in table using latitude and longitude. pls suggest any idea for fast nearest search technique.

**how to find common area using latitude,longitude and radius?**

we need to find common area using latitude,longitude and radius for only search that area not whole database search.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing a little basic of trigonometry and MySql, what i suggest to you is to try this solution

```
SELECT * FROM Places WHERE acos(sin([givenlatitude]) * sin(Lat) + cos([givenlatitude]) * cos(Lat) * cos(Lon - ([givenlongitude]))) * 6371 <= [givenDistance];
```

Where 6371 is Earth radius.

Comment: we already used this formula but it takes time for fetch result. we want to search not whole database only nearest area range

Comment: SELECT vb.id, vk.keyword, vb.business_address, ( 6371 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 28.684342 ) ) * COS( RADIANS( vb.latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( vb.longitude ) - RADIANS( 77.137941 ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( 28.684342 ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( vb.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM vendor_businesses vb, vendors_keyword vk
WHERE vk.vender_id = vb.vendor_id
AND vk.keyword_id=3258
HAVING distance <10